# Python: list comparison

Tags: python

please help me. If element in `b` is in `a`, then I want to put `a` (paired) in a new list (`C`).

```
a=['SMAD3', 'CYP11A1']
['SMAD3', 'ZNF83']
['SMAD3', 'PSMD11']
['SMAD3', 'MTF2']
['SMAD3', 'CFDP1']
['SMAD3', 'ST6GALNAC2']...

b=['NPR2']
['COL2A1']
['GNPTAG']
['ENPP1']
['COL6A1']
['WISP3']...
```

I coded like this:

```
C=[ ]
for data in a:
   for line in b:
  if ...
  C.append(a)
```

How can I fill the `if`?

Comment: Umm.. Can you show what output do you want? It is not quite clear.

Comment: Atleast use proper syntax, `a` and `b` doesn't even looks like lists.

Comment: If you are just checking if one element is in another, you can do `for data in b: if data in a:` and then do what you need there. But I may be misunderstanding your question :)

Comment: I want the output like this.

Comment: ['SMAD3', 'CYP11A1'] Just like a.

Comment: Your definitions of `a` and `b` still don't make any sense. Is `a` a list of 2-element lists? Please use proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a and b are lists:

```
c = []
for data in a:
    if data in b:
        c.append(data)
```

Or, as a list comprehension:

```
c = [data for data in a if data in b]
```

Comment: what if a=[['aaaa','bbbb'], ['ccccc', 'dddd']] and b=[['aaaa']] ??? how can I append?

Answer (score 0):

```
C=[ ]

for data in a:
    if data[0] in b or data[1] in b:
         C.append(data)
```

Comment: what if a=[['aaaa','bbbb'], ['ccccc', 'dddd']] and b=[['aaaa']] ??? how can I append?

Answer (score 0):

With this global solution `a` can be more than one pair and `b` can be more than one element in every inner list.

```
>>>a=[['ad','re','er'],['ew','fg']]  
>>>b=[['erw','dfger'],['we']]
```

Anyway here's how to do it:

```
c=[]  
modified_b=[]  
a=[['aaaa','bbbb'], ['ccccc', 'dddd']]  
b=[['aaaa']] 

for  i in b:  
     modified_b.extend(i)   # this will make b one list instead of list of lists  

for data in a:  
    for element in data:  
        if element in modified_b:  
            c.append(data)  
            break            #this will break the inner loop once you find b in a
```

Comment: Isn't it C.append(element) instead of C.append(data)?

Comment: @user1826018 I notice you don't accept any of the correct answers.Try to accept correct answers to your questions so you encourage the community to help you.Thanks